# layout inflater its not work i want in onlick functionality

Tags: java, android, html

I am not able to to understanding Layout Inflater  its not work in correct way please help me one. Layout Infleter if i click that that Images it's not going text page in that i wrote hi hello

```
public class Add_viewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView cartbtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_view);
        cartbtn = findViewById(R.id.cartbtn);

        cartbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                 View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_resource, null);
                TextView textid = view.findViewById(R.id.textid);
            }
        });
    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Add_viewActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cartbtn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cart_gray"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="274dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</LinearLayout>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hi hello"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout inflator cannot be inflated in on parent's onCreate(). You can only do it in fragment and call it from the parent's onCreate ().